# How to assert that an action was called

Tags: c#, tdd, rhino-mocks

I need to asset an action called by a mock component.

```
 public interface IDispatcher
    {
     void Invoke(Action action);
    }

    public interface IDialogService
    {
      void Prompt(string message);
    }

    public class MyClass
    {
    private readonly IDispatcher dispatcher;
    private readonly IDialogservice dialogService;
    public MyClass(IDispatcher dispatcher, IDialogService dialogService)
    {
     this.dispatcher = dispatcher;
    this.dialogService = dialogService;
    }

    public void PromptOnUiThread(string message)
    {
     dispatcher.Invoke(()=>dialogService.Prompt(message));
    }
    }

    ..and in my test..

   [TestFixture]
    public class Test
    {
     private IDispatcher mockDispatcher;
     private IDialogService mockDialogService;
    [Setup]
    public void Setup()
    {
     mockDispatcher = MockRepository.GenerateMock<IDispatcher>();
     mockDialogService = MockRepository.GenerateMock<IDialogService>();
    }

    [Test]
    public void Mytest()
    {
     var sut = CreateSut();
    sut.Prompt("message");

    //Need to assert that mockdispatcher.Invoke was called
    //Need to assert that mockDialogService.Prompt("message") was called.
    }
     public MyClass CreateSut()
    {
      return new MyClass(mockDipatcher,mockDialogService);
    }
    }
```

Maybe I need to restructure the code, but confused on that. Could you please advise?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You are actually testing this line of code:

```
dispatcher.Invoke(() => dialogService.Prompt(message));
```

Your class calls the mock to invoke a method on another mock. This is normally simple, you just need to make sure that Invoke is called with the correct arguments. Unfortunately, the argument is a lambda and not so easy to evaluate. But fortunately, it is a call to the mock which makes it easy again: just call it and verify that the other mock had been called:

```
Action givenAction = null;
mockDipatcher
  .AssertWasCalled(x => x.Invoke(Arg<Action>.Is.Anything))
  // get the argument passed. There are other solutions to achive the same
  .WhenCalled(call => givenAction = (Action)call.Arguments[0]);

// evaluate if the given action is a call to the mocked DialogService   
// by calling it and verify that the mock had been called:
givenAction.Invoke();
mockDialogService.AssertWasCalled(x => x.Prompt(message));
```

Comment: I believe it's mockDipatcher
  .Expect(x => x.Invoke(Arg<Action>.Is.Anything))
  // get the argument passed. There are other solutions to achive the same
  .WhenCalled(call => givenAction = (Action)call.Arguments[0]);

Comment: You can use `WhenCalled` either in combination with `Expect`, `Stub` or `AssertWasCalled` :-)

Answer (score 3):

You need first to put an expectation on your mock. For example I want to test that Invoke is called only once and that I don't care about the incoming parameters.

```
mockDispatcher.Expect(m => m.Invoke(null)).IgnoreArguments().Repeat.Once();
```

Then you have to assert and verify your expectations

```
mockDispatcher.VerifyAllExpectations();
```

you can do it the same way for the second mock, however it's a not good practice to have two mocks per unit test. You should test each in different tests.

For setting expectations please read http://ayende.com/wiki/Rhino+Mocks+Documentation.ashx