# Rhino Mocks IgnoreArguments() and testing if a lambda was called correctly

Tags: c#, unit-testing, rhino-mocks

Here's what I have:

```
   public interface IDataCenterMsmqWriter
   {
      void UpdateData(Action<DataCenterWcfProxy> action);
   }
```

System under test:

```
public class WcfService : IWcfService
{
    private readonly IDataCenterMsmqWriter _writer;

    public WcfService(IDataCenterMsmqWriter writer)
    {
        _writer = writer;
    }

    #region IWcfService members

    public void SendData(SomeData data)
    {
        _writer.UpdateData(d => d.SendVarData(data));
    }

    // other members of IWcfService elided
    #endregion
}
```

How do I test with Rhino Mocks setting the _writer as a Mock and want to test that the correct Action was called in the UpdateData method.

I've tried this:

```
// _writer is setup as a mock
var data = new SomeData();
_wcfServiceSUT.SendData(data);
_writer.AssertWasCalled(d => d.UpdateData(x => x.SendVarData(data));
```

doesn't work.

I can add the:

, p => p.IgnoreArguments() after the UpdateData inside the AssertWasCalled, but that does not give me what I want, to make sure SendVarData was called with the data variable.

I've looked at this:

[How to assert that an action was called](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6413040/rhino-mocks-how-to-assert-that-an-action-was-called)

but my Action isn't mocked like mockDialogService in his example.

Is there a way to test if an Action or Func was called properly with the right input parameters, etc?

Comment: Is `DataCenterWcfProxy.SendVarData()` a virtual method, or could you put an interface in place?

Comment: no it's just a public method on the interface that will serialize over WCF.

Comment: It is an option to add an interface `IDataCenterWcfProxy` that gets implemented by `DataCenterWcfProxy` and used by the `Update` method of `IDataCenterMsmqWriter`?

Answer (score 1):

The UpdateData should be virtual otherwise rhino mock can not overwrite method

Answer (score 1):

The **best** way to verify that an Action or Func was called with the correct parameters would be to use the [.WhenCalled extension](http://ayende.com/wiki/Rhino%20Mocks%203.5.ashx?AspxAutoDetectCookieSupport=1#Accessingthemethodargumentsdirectly). An example can be found in the following 
[Google groups discussion](https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/rhinomocks/xvCChzohSuE).

This example shows how to leverage the **Expected vs. Actual** output rather than *expectations being met or not*.