# Assert a method was called whilst verifying the parameters are correct

Tags: unit-testing, mocking, c#-3.0, rhino-mocks-3.5

Given the following snippet from my test:

```
var mockProvider = MockRepository.GenerateMock<IItemProvider>();

var target = new ItemService(mockProvider);

target.SaveItem(item);
```

Internally `target.SaveItem` makes a call like this:

`provider.SaveItem(new SaveContract(item.Id, user, contents));` where `provider` is the local name for the `mockProvider` passed in.

How do I:

1. Verify `provider.SaveItem` is called ***whilst also***
2. Asserting that the values of `item.Id`, `user` and `contents` are as they should be.

I think I might be able to use mockProvider.AssertWasCalled but can't figure out the syntax to set the condition of the parameters passed to the constructor of `SaveContract`.

TIA

Comment: See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6413040/rhino-mocks-how-to-assert-that-an-action-was-called

Comment: But `AssertWasCalled` return void, how do I call `WhenCalled` on it?

Comment: Oh I see only `Expect` works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok so based on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6413040/rhino-mocks-how-to-assert-that-an-action-was-called) I did something like the following:

```
var mockProvider = MockRepository.GenerateMock<IItemProvider>();
var target = new ItemService(mockProvider);
Item testItem = null;

mockProvider.Expect(c => c.SaveItem(Arg<Item>.Is.Anything))
.WhenCalled(call =>
{
    testItem = (Item)call.Arguments[0];
});


target.SaveItem(item);//item initialised elsewhere


Assert.AreEqual(item.Id, testItem.Id);
```